# Need help using an Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I'm completely new to iterators. I have an ArrayList named "Test" with String objects. How would I go about using an iterator class? I've tried everything I can think of, it's just not making sense. Thanks for the help.

Say I have an Iterator named "iter". I need to step through my ArrayList in search of a certain String. When that String is found, I need to add it to a different ArrayList named "test2".

```
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    if(iter.next() == sampleString) {
        test2.add(sampleString);
    }
}
```

Only problem with this, is that when I call next() it moves the pointer to the next String, ignoring the first String in the ArrayList. How would I implement this??

Comment: I don't see how your example would be "ignoring the first String." I would advise you to be careful about using == for object comparison, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your not quite 100% on how Iterator.next() works

This is copied directly from the Java API

E next() -- Returns the next element in the iteration.

What this means is that .next() will return an object then move to the next item in the list.

You need to store the returned object when calling next()

```
while(iter.hasNext()) 
{
    String temp = iter.next();
    //this is a more old school method but more true to form. 
    //== doesn't necessarily do equality checks on all objects the way
    //you would think 
    if(temp.equals(sampleString)) 
    {
        test2.add(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a temp was the key. Thanks

Comment: Using `compareTo()` in place of `equals()` is bad form.  it obfuscates what you are doing.  if you only care if 2 things are equal, then use `equals()`.

Comment: @jtahlborn My comments about it being more true to form was really only relative to his original version which simply uses the == operator. Although it will behave as desired with a String, a new programmer may then begin to believe it will check for equality in terms of specific values within objects where it is really seeing if the references to those objects are equal. I completely spaced that equals will perform the same task. I agree it is better and easier to read. I updated the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need one. The ArrayList is already Iterable! :-D

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("Hello");
test.add("world");
for(String str : test) System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: I need to create an iterator. It's part of a school project and I NEED to implement an iterator to show that I understand the concept.

Comment: Then I recommend posting what your attempts were and we can go from there. :)

Comment: And tell your professor to update their lesson plans and stop using outdated technologies!

Comment: how exactly is iterator outdated?  the Iterable works using an iterator, and there are still _plenty_ of situations where you need to use the iterator directly.

Comment: @jtahlborn By and large, the construction of iterators is inferior to using the Collections framework with custom comparators if necessary.

Comment: @glowcoder - i'm sorry, that comment made no sense to me.  what do custom comparators have to do with iteration over a collection?  how do i delete an element during iteration without using the iterator directly?  how do i reverse iterate a List without using the ListIterator?

Answer (score 4):

Iterators are generally used like this:

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String nextString = iter.next();
    // Do something with the string...
}
```

Some (myself included) will prefer the enhanced for loop:

```
for (String nextString : listOfStrings) {
    // Do something with the string
}
```

The for loop avoids the need for getting an explicit Iterator reference and includes the `nextString` variable declaration, keeping it concise and properly scoped.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator is simply something that understands how to traverse a given data structure.

What is it that you aren't understanding?

For a `List` an iterator would keep track of its current position in the list and understand how to get the next element in the list.  For something like a list, it's relatively simple, but you could also define an iterator for some other arbitrary data structure that isn't as simple as a list.  You could also define one that does something differently like traverse the list backwards.  If you have specific questions about iterators, update your question and we'll take a stab at it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Iterator is a means of traversing a collection of items. Adhering to that statement, the java.util.Collection **extends** Iterable (`public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E>`). i.e all collection classes are [Iterable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) in **someway**. [iterator()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator%28%29) is the method to get a handle to that [Iterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). Once you have the handle you can traverse through the items.

I highlighted someway because not all Iterator's allow bi-directional traversal. [ListIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) allows this.

I'd rewrite your code as below

```
for(String s : myCollection)
{
   if(s.equals(sampleString))
   {
      test.add(s);
   }
}
```